# Error to write AWS configure in Visual Studio Code

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code

When I write in Visual Studio Code AWS configure and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I get this error:

> aws : The term 'aws' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - aws configure
> - 

What can I to solve this in Visual Studio Code?

> - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (aws:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Have you installed the [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)?

Answer (score 0):

[Install the awscli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html)

Then run the command:

```
aws configure
```